# Power BI Code for filtering. Debugging Codes in M language ( Creating a column in Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am having error Please can you help out, as I am new here

= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if ([Application Name] = "BBK" and (Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_ADMIN_BBK") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_UPDATE_BBK") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_BBK")) then "YES" else if [Application Name] = "CBJ" and (Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_ADMIN_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_UPDATE_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_EXECUTE_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_READ_CBJ")) then "YES"else if [Application Name] = "NEX" and Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_NEX") then "YES" else if [Application Name] = "SNR" and Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_SNR" ) then "YES" else "NO"))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to tell what you are doing, but try

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 

if (
[Application Name] = "BBK" and (Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_ADMIN_BBK") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_UPDATE_BBK") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_BBK"))) then "YES"
else if ([Application Name] = "CBJ" and (Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_ADMIN_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_UPDATE_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_EXECUTE_CBJ") or Text.Contains([Entitlement Key],"_READ_CBJ"))) then "YES"
else if [Application Name] = "NEX" and Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_NEX") then "YES"
else if [Application Name] = "SNR" and Text.Contains([Entitlement Key], "_READ_SNR" ) then "YES"
else "NO"
)
```

I did what you should have done -- tried this piece by piece, making sure that each row evaluated before adding the next.  You had too few parenthesis on some places and too many in others